# HTML to text with custom on link click listener

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This is the sample HTML String,

```
<span class=\"proflinkWrapper\"><span class=\"proflinkPrefix\">+<\/span><a class=\"proflink\" href=\"https://plus.google.com/114461178896543099856\" oid=\"114461178896543099856\">Elon Musk<\/a><\/span> hey
```

Using HTML.fromHtml, I get this,

```
+Elon Musk hey
```

On click of +Elon Musk, it takes me to the browser but I want the corresponding URL and use it in my app, hit me up with suggestions people! (I don't want spannables, since the content is very dynamic and is in HTML format)

Is it possible to intercept Html.fromHtml and get the URL and make it not open in a browser and just use it in my app as I wish?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the URL and display it?

Comment: @Chris not exactly. I want the url mapped with the corresponding text so that, I can implement my own on click listeners.

Eg: Elon Musk will be mapped with https://plus.google.com/114461178896543099856

Comment: Adding a LinkMovementMethod is probably what you need, an example can be found here: https://darshangr.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/text-view-with-hyperlinks-and-link-only-listener-android/

Comment: @Chris I found the same to be helpful. Thanks for your response! I have added my answer in kotlin with customisable onClickListener passed through the constructor. Please check it https://stackoverflow.com/a/52202701/4619977

Answer (score 2):

I have found a work around by modifying my LinkMovementMethod

```
import android.text.Spannable
import android.text.style.URLSpan
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.widget.TextView

class MyLinkMovementMethod(var onUrlClickListener: (String) -> Unit) : android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod() {

    override fun onTouchEvent(widget: TextView, buffer: Spannable, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val action = event.action

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            var x = event.x.toInt()
            var y = event.y.toInt()
            x -= widget.totalPaddingLeft
            y -= widget.totalPaddingTop
            x += widget.scrollX
            y += widget.scrollY

            val layout = widget.layout
            val line = layout.getLineForVertical(y)
            val off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x.toFloat())

            val link = buffer.getSpans(off, off, URLSpan::class.java)
            if (link.isNotEmpty()) {
                val url = link[0].url
                if (url.contains("https") or url.contains("tel") or url.contains("mailto") or url.contains("http") or url.contains("https") or url.contains("www")) {
                    onUrlClickListener(url)
                }
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event)
    }
}
```

You can add your own listeners by modifying the code, for now, I have added a listener for URL clicks. You can use it in your code by adding this line:

```
textview.movementMethod = MyLinkMovementMethod(fun(url: String) {
                        Log.e("URL", url)
                    })
```

The code is in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

We may just get the `href` value like this:

```
String ht = "<span class=\"proflinkWrapper\"><span class=\"proflinkPrefix\">+</span><a class=\"proflink\" href=\"https://plus.google.com/114461178896543099856\" oid=\"114461178896543099856\">Elon Musk</a></span> hey";

int hrefIndex = ht.indexOf("href=");
if (hrefIndex >= 0) {
    int startIndex = hrefIndex + "href=".length();
    int endIndex = ht.indexOf('"', hrefIndex + "href=".length() + 1);

    if (startIndex > 0 && endIndex > 0) {
        String href = ht.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I said, the content is dynamic. I may have multiple hrefs and I have to parse it accordingly. I don't want to use spanables too. I want to override the HTML.fromHtml to add my own click listeners instead of opening the browser.